# Download OpenTopoMap bulk data

Tags: database, download, opentopomap

Is it possible to download full regions of OpenTopoMap data ?

I saw that it is possible for Garmin devices (http://garmin.opentopomap.org), however, I am looking for jpg/png tiles and I could not find any easy way to convert Garmin format to tiles.

I am interested by OpenTopoMap as I guess this is the best data available for hiking in Europe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean "OpenTopoMap tiles", not "data".

You can render your own with their open-source style from https://github.com/der-stefan/OpenTopoMap

That would be the nicest and most independent way.

You *could* mass-download their tiles with any suitable tool or script, but please ask them before for permission and rate-limits, see https://opentopomap.org/credits

Comment: I have checked the "howto" on the linked repository and I wonder if this process will generate directly all the bitmap tiles, or if I still need the web server to generate them.

Comment: You would have renderd running and it will create the tiles on demand. You can bulk pre-render tiles with tools like https://github.com/naturalatlas/tilemantle or just do it all on demand when you do your mass requesting.