# How can I use OpenTopoMap Garmin Maps files with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, tiles, garmin, opentopomap

We can download OpenTopoMap bulk export from https://garmin.opentopomap.org/. Vector or bitmap files? I'm not sure and I need PNG files.

This is useful for GPS devices, but this can be also useful when you want to use OpenTopoMap offline, or with a slow internet connexion (because instead of download tiles from opentopomap.org, tiles are retrieved from bulk export).

How can I get a [PNG tile](https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/16/32752/21788.png) from the previous [files](https://garmin.opentopomap.org/europe/monaco/otm-monaco-basecamp.zip)?

Is there a very simple (python) program to read theses data? 
For example `$ the_magic_program 16_32752_21788` returns an image data.

Comment: Which GIS software are you using?

Comment: I use leafletjs with my browser.

Comment: Simplest way to download tiles for https://opentopomap.org/ map to local machine and then use tiles from there would probably be SAS.Planet app, here is one possible download link https://www.learngeom.com/2021/08/latest-version-sasplanet-software-download.html. If the latest version of the app does not work, try an older one. I'm using one from 2019.

Answer (score 2):

You could use your own local tile server. Here is a complete walk-through how to set up a OpenTopoMap tile server:

- https://github.com/der-stefan/OpenTopoMap/blob/master/mapnik/README.md

---

You could also set up a local proxy server (with content caching). The initial access for a map area will still be slow but recurring requests will be faster since the proxy is local:

- https://www.easytechjunkie.com/what-is-proxy-server-caching.htm
- https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

---

This [answer to another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278212/21355) suggest:

> You could mass-download their tiles with any suitable tool or script, but please ask them before for permission and rate-limits, see https://opentopomap.org/credits 
>
> https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278212/21355

You could write a simple Python script downloading all tiles for your desired map area. However, as mentioned in bugmenot123's answer, please ask them before for permission and rate-limits.

---

**Note:** I missed the part about the slow internet connection in your question at first. Sorry. Just ignore the next part of this answer. I leave it in case it's helpful for someone else.

If you want to use it in Leaflet, you may be able to use one of their **tile server**:

- `https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

Additional information and terms of use on their [About page](https://www.opentopomap.org/about).

Here is an example using Leaflet with `https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>OpenTopoMap Leaflet Example</title>
    
  <!-- test code / integrity attribute removed for readability -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    
  <div id="map" style="height: calc(100vh - 1rem);"></div>

  <script>

      const map = L.map('map')
          .setView([44.6475, -63.580278], 11);

      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: `Kartendaten: © OpenStreetMap-Mitwirkende, SRTM 
                                  | Kartendarstellung: © OpenTopoMap (CC-BY-SA)`
      }).addTo(map);

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```